# Getting an error when I switch to another link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud, mern, mui-datatable

So I created a sidebar wherein i have different links, such as `orders, users, products`. So, when I click fast at a different URL, I get an error.  I also create a loading state so every time the URL changes, it reloads. But this most happened when I click on to **order** link. I also tried to put optional chaining inside the columns.

Should I also put a loading state in app.js? which is mostly consist of route?

The column came from the App.js

List.jsx

```
const List = ({columns}) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const id = location.pathname.split('/')[1]
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [data,setData] = useState([])
 
  useEffect(() =>{
    const getData = async () =>{
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get(`/${id}`)
        setData(res.data)
        setLoading(false)
      } catch (error) {
        
      }
    }
    getData()
  },[id, data, columns])

  return (
   <>
    {loading ? (
                <BeatLoader 
                color="#36d7b7" 
                loading={loading}
                size={50}
                aria-label="Loading Spinner"
                data-testid="loader"
              />

    ) : (
       <div className="list">
       <Sidebar/>
       <div className="listContainer">
         <Navbar/>
         <Datatable columns={columns} data={data} setData={setData}/>
       </div>
     </div>
    )}
   </>
  )
}

export default List
```

Datatable.jsx

```
const Datatable = ({data,setData, columns}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  //const [data, setData] = useState(userRows);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false)
  },[data, setData, columns])

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setData(data.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  const actionColumn = [
    {
      field: "action",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 200,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <div className="cellAction">
            <Link to="/users/test" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
              <div className="viewButton">View</div>
            </Link>
            <div
              className="deleteButton"
              onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row._id)}
            >
              Delete
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div className="datatable">
      <div className="datatableTitle">
      <div className="search">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
          <SearchOutlinedIcon />
        </div>
      </div>
      {loading ? (
         <BeatLoader 
         color="#36d7b7" 
         loading={loading}
         size={50}
         aria-label="Loading Spinner"
         data-testid="loader"
       />
        
      ): (
        <DataGrid
        className="datagrid"
        rows={data}
        getRowId={(row) => row._id}
        columns={columns.concat(actionColumn)}
        pageSize={9}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[9]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Datatable;
```

This is the error I'm receiving, it came from the products[0]

[image]

column.js

```
export const orderColumn = [
  {field: "_id", headerName: "Transaction", width: 220},
  {
    field: "buyerId",
    headerName: "Buyer ID" ,
    width: 150,
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return (
        <div className="cellWithImg">
             {params.row?.userId?.studentId}
        </div>
      )
    },
  },
  {
    field: "amount",
    headerName:"Price" ,
    width: 150,
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return (
        <div className="cellWithImg">
            {params.row?.amount}
        </div>
      )
    },
  },
  {
    field: "products",
    headerName: "Product",
    width: 150,
    renderCell: (params) =>{

      return (
        <div className="cellWithImg">
          <img className="cellImg" src={params.row?.products[0]?.productId?.img} alt="avatar" />
          {params.row?.products[0]?.productId?.title}
        </div>
      )
    }
  },
  {
    field: "seller",
    headerName: "Seller",
    width: 150,
    renderCell: (params) =>{
      return (
      <div>
          {params.row?.products[0]?.sellerId?.studentId}
      </div>
      )
    }
  },
  {
    field: "location and time",
    headerName: "Location and Time",
    width: 150,
    renderCell: (params) =>{
      return (
      <div >
          {params.row?.location} ||  {params.row?.time}
      </div>
      )
    }
  },
  {
    field: "status",
    headerName: "Status",
    width: 150,
    renderCell: (params) =>{
      return (
      <div >
          {params.row?.status} 
      </div>
      )
    }
  }
]
```

**EDIT**

Additional Info, this is what I received when I call

```
 {
        "_id": "636357777877c919bb2cfa45",
        "userId": {
            "_id": "636355527877c919bb2cdf22",
            "studentId": "1234567891"
        },
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": {
                    "_id": "636355a07877c919bb2cdfdc",
                    "title": "Cabinet Update Shoe",
                    "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tua-ecom.appspot.com/o/1667454433424%5Bobject%20File%5D?alt=media&token=fb6cd8f1-a204-4a63-bcc2-7de2c93fd544"
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "sellerId": {
                    "_id": "636355187877c919bb2cdf1f",
                    "studentId": "1234567890"
                },
                "_id": "636357777877c919bb2cfa46"
            }
        ],
        "amount": 100,
        "location": "Guard House",
        "time": "8:00",
        "status": "pending",
        "tax": 1,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-03T05:53:59.997Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-03T05:53:59.997Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Optional chaining will not work for `_SOME_PROPERTY[_SOME_INDEX]`

Try changing

```
{params.row?.products[0]?.productId?.title}
```

to

```
{params.row?.products[0] ? params.row?.products[0].productId?.title : '-'}
```

and at every place where you use optional chaining with array index.

Comment: its not working, i still got an error, I updated some additional infos.

Comment: you have optional chaining not only there. i just put example for one occurrence :) you need to change them all

Comment: I change it all, but still receiving error.  **EDIT** i delete all fields consist of  `params.row?.products[0]` and only use your example for the title itself.

Comment: still the same error even with this change? this is weird

Comment: is there anyway i can reload the whole List component? Because it works only when the `BeatLoader`?

Answer (score 0):

after spending on hour trying to optional chain the whole column and using the same component, I created a separate component for OrderList.jsx

I wasted too much time for forcing all api to use single component

```
const ListOrder = ({columns}) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const id = location.pathname.split('/')[1]
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [data,setData] = useState([])
 
  useEffect(() =>{
    const getData = async () =>{
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get(`/order`)
          setData(res.data)
          setLoading(false)
      } catch (error) {
        
      }
    }
    getData()
  },[id, data, columns])

  return (
   <>
    {loading ? (
                <BeatLoader 
                color="#36d7b7" 
                loading={loading}
                size={50}
                aria-label="Loading Spinner"
                data-testid="loader"
              />

    ) : (
       <div className="list">
       <Sidebar/>
       <div className="listContainer">
         <Navbar/>
         <Datatable columns={columns} id={id} data={data} setData={setData}/>
       </div>
     </div>
    )}
   </>
  )
}

export default ListOrder
```